Flutter Scheduled Local Notification is not working
I'm doing a To Do App using flutter, and i want to add a reminder to app. When users set a reminder with selecting date and time, app will send the notifications like an alarm. But whatever i do it is not working. Please can anyone tell me where i do wrong? Thanks a lot.
main.dart file
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_1/utilities/send_notification.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'pages/home_page.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;

void main() async {
  // init the hive
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // init the local notification
  await SendNotification().initNotification(); // class'ın içindeki fonksiyonu burada çalıştırmış olduk
  tz.initializeTimeZones();

  // open a box
  var box = await Hive.openBox('mybox');
  
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.pink[200], foregroundColor: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
}

home_page.dart file
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_1/data/database.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_1/utilities/reminder_box.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app_1/utilities/send_notification.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import '../utilities/dialog_box.dart';
import '../utilities/todo_tile.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // reference the hive box
  final _myBox = Hive.box('mybox');
  ToDoDatabase db = ToDoDatabase();

  @override
  void initState() {

    // if this is the first opening the app, then create default data
    if(_myBox.get("TODOLIST") == null) {
      db.createInitialData();
    } else {
      // there already exists data
      db.loadData();
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  // text controller
  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  // checkbox was tapped
  void checkBoxChanged(bool? value, int index) {
    setState(() {
      db.toDoList[index][1] = !db.toDoList[index][1];
    });
    db.updateDatabase();
  }

  // save new task
  void saveNewTask() {
    setState(() {
      db.toDoList.add([_controller.text, false]); // _controller is the new task. .text converts it to the string.
      _controller.clear();
    });
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
     db.updateDatabase();
  }

  // creating a new task
  void createNewTask() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context){
        return DialogBox(
          controller: _controller,
          onSave: saveNewTask,
          onCancel: () {
            _controller.clear(); // TextField içindeki metni sil
            Navigator.of(context).pop(); // dialog kutusunu kapat
          }
        );
      },
    );
  }

  // deleting the task
  void deleteTask(int index) {
    setState(() {
      db.toDoList.removeAt(index);
    });
      db.updateDatabase();
  }

    void sendNotification() {            
    SendNotification().scheduleNotification(
      title: 'To Do', 
      body: 'It\'s time to do something!',
      scheduledNotificationDateTime: scheduleTime,
    );
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  // reminding the task
  void remindTask(int index) {
    showDialog(
      context: context, 
      builder: (context){
        return ReminderBox(
          onSetReminder: sendNotification,
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink[100],
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 4,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text("TO DO"),
        titleTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 32),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink[300],
        onPressed: createNewTask,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: db.toDoList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ToDoTile(
            taskName: db.toDoList[index][0],
            taskCompleted: db.toDoList[index][1], 
            onChanged: (value) => checkBoxChanged(value, index),
            deleteFunction: (context) => deleteTask(index),
            reminderFunction: (context) => remindTask(index),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

reminder_box.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_datetime_picker_plus/flutter_datetime_picker_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart';

import 'send_notification.dart';

DateTime scheduleTime = DateTime.now();

class ReminderBox extends StatefulWidget {
  ReminderBox({super.key, required this.onSetReminder});

  VoidCallback onSetReminder;

  @override
  State<ReminderBox> createState() => _ReminderBoxState();
}

class _ReminderBoxState extends State<ReminderBox> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    scheduleTime = DateTime.now();
    SendNotification().initNotification();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink[300],
      content: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(35),
        height: 250,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.access_time, color: Colors.white),
                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                  Text(
                    "Date & Time:",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 16,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text(
                '${scheduleTime.day}/${scheduleTime.month}/${scheduleTime.year} ${scheduleTime.hour}:${scheduleTime.minute}',
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                DatePicker.showDateTimePicker(
                  context,
                  showTitleActions: true,
                  onChanged: (date) => setState(() => scheduleTime = date),
                  onConfirm: (date) {},
                );
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: widget.onSetReminder, 
              child: Text('SET REMINDER', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
           ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


send_notifications.dart file
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

class SendNotification {
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/todo');

    var initializationSettingsIOS = DarwinInitializationSettings(
        requestAlertPermission: true,
        requestBadgePermission: true,
        requestSoundPermission: true,
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification:
            (int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) async {});

    var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse:
            (NotificationResponse notificationResponse) async {});
  }

  notificationDetails() {
    return const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails('channelId', 'channelName',
            importance: Importance.max),
        iOS: DarwinNotificationDetails());
  }

  Future showNotification(
      {int id = 0, String? title, String? body, String? payLoad}) async {
    return notificationsPlugin.show(
        id, title, body, await notificationDetails());
  }

  Future scheduleNotification(
      {int id = 0,
      String? title,
      String? body,
      String? payLoad,
      required DateTime scheduledNotificationDateTime}) async {
    return notificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
        id,
        title,
        body,
        tz.TZDateTime.from(
          scheduledNotificationDateTime,
          tz.local,
        ),
        await notificationDetails(),
        androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
        uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
            UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime);
  }
}

AndroidManifest.xml file
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <application
        android:label="TO DO"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@drawable/todo">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:showWhenLocked="true"
            android:turnScreenOn="true">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility?hl=en and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

pubspec.yaml file
name: flutter_app_1
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none'
version: 0.1.0

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.3.3 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  hive: ^2.2.3
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
  timezone: ^0.9.3

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_slidable: ^3.1.0
  flutter_local_notifications: ^17.1.2
  flutter_datetime_picker_plus: ^2.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  hive_generator: ^1.1.3
  flutter_lints: ^3.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.1.11

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true



    <receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
<receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<receiver android:exported="false" android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ActionBroadcastReceiver" />

Add these lines before <activity> tag in AndroidManifest.xml
I've created a similar application that demonstrates this. You can check it out for reference: https://github.com/s4nk37/flow

Thank you, i solved the problem. When i decrease the version of flutter local notification it started to work.
